# The Mnemonic Forgotten

Tags: knowledge

In school, one of my teachers, Mister Ball, gave us a mnemonic to remember the... something. Unfortunately, it has been a very long time and I only remember half of the mnemonic. I don't even remember what it was for.

Here is what I *do* remember:

> ?
>   ?
>   Mister Manganese
>   Senior Senior

The first two lines rhymed with each other, but I don't think they were real words.

**What was the first half of the mnemonic, and what was the mnemonic's meaning?**

Comment: "Mr Mn Sr Sr"...

Comment: @Deusovi rese, nese, mrmn, srsr ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole mnemonic is:

> Reesee Neesee Mister Manganese Senior Senior

How I got there:

> Mr. is short for Mister, Mn is the symbol for Manganese, Sr is short for Senior.

(Thanks to Raystafarian for the first two lines)

And the meaning of the mnemonic is:

> RESE NESE MRMN SRSR which is the endings for definite articles in German.

Comment: "reesee neesee" rhyme and aren't real words.

Comment: @Raystafarian I wasn't sure it the first two lines somehow were related to the way I got the last two, but those would fit his clue description

Comment: Thanks for helping me remember that _the mnemonic_ Herr Ball taught me.

Comment: @Will is the herr ball a clue or a joke?

Comment: @Ray 'twas a joke